# Windows Phone 8 with Caliburn.Micro 2.0

Tags: windows-phone-8, caliburn.micro

I want to write a sample application on Windows Phone 8 using Caliburn.Micro. I have found some tutorials but no one uses Caliburn.Micro 2.0. If anybody could give me any "Hello World" I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the same as using Caliburn.Micro 1.5.x from all the tutorials. The sample for WP7 also applies to WP8: https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/tree/master/samples/Caliburn.Micro.HelloWP71